# PHP/MySql: Login page isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a login page using php that checks the users database in mysql and checks if the typed username and password match, if not, it shows the message ]invalid but for me, even if i type in the correct username and password it shows the message invalid. Whats the problem with my codes. BTW connection.php page contains the codes for linking the page to the database.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['tsmUsername'])) {
            $username=$_POST['tsmUsername'];
            $password=$_POST['tsmPassword'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$username AND password=$password LIMIT 1";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
        {
            echo "You have successfully logged in";
        }
        else{
            echo "Invalid";
        }
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="login" id="login" method="POST" action="">
        <table cellpadding="5" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center">
                    <h2>login </h2>
                    <hr>
                    <h6> Fill the below information to login</h6>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="30%" align="right">
                    <label for="tsmUsername">Username</label>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="text" name="tsmUsername" id="tsmUsername" required="required">
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="30%" align="right">
                    <label for="tsmPassword">Your password</label>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="password" name="tsmPassword" id="tsmPassword" required="required">
                </td>           
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login Now">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: you're kidding? *username=$username AND password=$password* take a look at your **sql query** ...

Comment: SQL injection, etc....., escape with single quotes....

Comment: might want to think about also sanitizing that a little bit  -- the username:  `'' OR username like '%'`  results in a valid login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
```

and are you not using any algorithm for securing password? it's very easy to hack the site